# SpriteKit Custom Node Boundary

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, physics, boundary

I need to make a custom node boundary around this shape: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pn1J.jpg

When I use the traditional rectangle shape, it’s not accurate to when the main player collides with the rounded edges.

Here is my code so far:

```
rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rightWall.size)
    rightWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.platform
    rightWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.player
    rightWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.player
    rightWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    rightWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the init method that takes a texture to generate the physics body.

```
init(texture texture: SKTexture, size size: CGSize)
```

Comment: Where would this go in my code? And how would I put the image name in as the texture?

Comment: Replace the `SKPhysicsBody` initializer that is takes `rectangleOfSize` with the one that takes a texture and a size.